# If dogs could talk

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

We all know the Simpsons' little greyhound.
But what is Bart's pet *saying* in this picture?

[image: Santa's Little Helper says: "Amethysts or Hamster's Toy Rheostats My Mossy Threat"]

Comment: Wittgenstein: "If a dog could speak, we could not understand him."  Philosophical Investigations, p.223 + my edit  :)

Comment: His name is Santa's Little Helper

Comment: @CanadianLuke - Yes. I considered saving the puzzle for Christmas and using his name in the title.. Maybe I'll do another puzzle around then.

Comment: Surely Simpsons' rather than Simpson's?

Comment: @Silverfish - No, that was deliberate. I was referring specifically to Bart. That was necessary to indicate that it was his pet rather than the whole family's.

Comment: I'm still not sure "the Simpson's little greyhound" is quite right. I guess it is the "the" in front which is confusing me!

Comment: Well Bart is the Simpson who has the pet. Is it the grammar that's your concern or the validity of the clue?

Comment: @chasly Just the grammar. I don't think that if John Smith, of the Smith family ("the Smiths") had a pet dog, I would call that dog "the Smith's dog" to signify it belonged to John alone and not his entire family.

Comment: I think we could say, "I know the Smith family. The Smith who has a dog is John." However we're getting into grammar rather than puzzling so maybe we should stop or move to English Language SE ;-)

Comment: @LamarLatrell - True, but then not many people could understand Wittgenstein ;-) --- For the record most dog owners understand what their dogs are saying only too well. It usually relates to food and going for walks! – I don't suppose old Witters ever had a pet. Just another armchair philosopher.

Comment: Santa's Little Helper is the family dog, not just Bart's.

Comment: @dennisdeems - See my answer to Silverfish above and the subsequent discussion.

Comment: I did, and you're wrong.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It must be:

> **Eat My Shorts!** 
>  He's repeating anagrams of Bart's catchphrase. What a clever dog, that Santa's Little Helper! 
>  For the record, Deusovi answered first (+1), verifying that they were all anagrams, but didn't come up with the one which most fits the puzzle.

He might also be barking **"HANDWOVEN AT CAMO"** ;)

Comment: Actually I think you probably did get the extra bit because you mentioned the word 'ca------se' . I've given my answer anyway.

Comment: I didn't consider the wordplay with "pet" until you answered. I haven't personally heard it used other than in the idiom "teacher's pet", but I looked it up, and it indeed can mean "a thing particularly cherished".

Comment: I was amazed at how quickly the two answers appeared! I suppose I should expect that on a puzzling community!

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Don't be amazed: this one was super easy. There are online resources for getting anagrams, so all you have to do is stick in one of the phrases from the question and see what results come out.

Comment: @rand al'thor  I did this without those resources, but they are quite abundant. Unfortunately, most of their output is jibberish, like Handwoven at Camo, which I did use a website to create :)

Comment: Good point! I just checked and there are a LOT of fairly meaningful anagrams of this phrase. Not so easy after all then :-)

Comment: @randal'thor - Yes but surely there aren't many others  so appropriate to the subject matter as Deusovi's - You have to admit that was quite a coincidence.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Indeed! So much of a coincidence that I wonder if it could have been intentional on the part of the people who made the show...

Comment: @randal'thor - Not according to this, "The real history behind the phrase is that Nancy Cartwright, Bart's voice actor, improvised the line during a table read. She first said it as a prank when she was in her high school marching band at Fairmont High School. "  http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/Eat_My_Shorts!

Comment: Dry banana hippy hat!

Comment: If I could start this question again, I would omit the anagrams and just have a blank speech balloon. That surely would have made it tough to crack, yet the tricksy bit would still have been in place.

Answer (score 12):

Is it...

> "Homer's tasty"?

I guessed this because

> each line was an anagram of the others, and this seemed to be the most logical missing anagram.

Comment: Well no - but I am flabbergasted by the fact that it could yield this answer!  It is not the one I had in mind.  When you see the reasoning you will understand why mine is more apposite. I'm still amazed by the coincidence.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: Yeah, I figured there was a more 'elegant' answer. Still trying to find it - my original thought was that there would be some sort of anagram indicator and that's currently what I'm looking for. (e.g. "GSGE" cluing "scrambled eggs")

Answer (score 9):

I'm amazed by the responses to this question in so many ways. Here was my intended formulation of the answer:

> **Eat My Shorts!**

The reason is:

> "What is Bart's pet saying?" can be interpreted as "What is Bart's favourite saying."  The anagrams weren't actually needed to answer the question!