# Repeat the Method to Solve the Clues

Tags: riddle, word, cryptic-clues

*Below, you will find a list of clues! Each clue has an answer that is no more than two words and is related to each other answer in a noticeable (albeit perhaps not immediately obvious) way. Discover the answers to the clues and their intricate relationships!*

---

### Clues

- A bearlike whale
- Attire of an ancient, mysterious sorcerer
- "Cool pointer!"
- A blighted sort of metal
- One who expeditions through deep time
- Keeps using the same data
- Providing someone with assets, maybe
- Destroyer of subatomic particles
- Wrath of the mailman
- Once again, the mongrels choose to partake
- Doctors act like pigs
- The Lord of the Sound
- Weeps over grains
- One who takes good care of his money?
- The companions we have
- Deface a rotting body
- An indecent vegetable
- One who wets the bed
- Scampers all over
- An unpleasant idiot
- Intriguing symbols on an intriguing object
- The more voluptuous brother
- Pots of snails
- An old decision point
- Sounds like a spicy dish
- An area where certain clouds might form

---

Hint:

> There have been [ones like this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/19947/literally-no-idea) before, but this one is mine. It has its own, special letters and its own, special twist. Starting with a pattern similar to the [ones like this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18768/if-dogs-could-talk) is a good idea, but to solve the puzzle fully you'll have to figure out my own special gimmick.

Comment: *"Cool pointer!"* I instantly thought of a cursor.

Comment: They sound like [these](http://xkcd.com/1563/) and [these](http://xkcd.com/1568/)...

Comment: @warspyking that's not a bad thing to be thinking of...

Comment: This is just wonderful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All answers are

> anagrams using the letters RECURSION + A-Z depending on the clue's place on the list.

A bearlike whale:

> A- URSINE ORCA

Attire of an ancient, mysterious sorcerer:

> B- RUNIC ROBES

"Cool pointer!":

> C- NICE CURSOR

A blighted sort of metal:

> D- CURSED IRON

One who expeditions through deep time:

> E- EON CRUISER

Keeps using the same data:

> F- RECURS INFO

Providing someone with assets, maybe:

> G- RESOURCING

Destroyer of subatomic particles:

> H- ION CRUSHER

Wrath of the mailman:

> I- COURIER SIN

Once again, the mongrels choose to partake:

> J- CURS REJOIN

Doctors act like pigs:

> K- CURERS OINK

The Lord of the Sound:

> L- SONIC RULER

Weeps over grains:

> M- MOURNS RICE

One who takes good care of his money?:

> N- COIN NURSER

The companions we have:

> O- OUR CRONIES

Deface a rotting body:

> P- RUIN CORPSE

An indecent vegetable:

> Q- RISQUE CORN

One who wets the bed:

> R-URIC SNORER

Scampers all over:

> S- SCURRIES ON

An unpleasant idiot:

> T- SOUR CRETIN

Intriguing symbols on an intriguing object:

> U- CURIO RUNES

The more voluptuous brother:

> V- CURVIER SON

Pots of snails:

> W- COWRIE URNS

An old decision point:

> X- SENIOR CRUX

Sounds like a spicy dish:

> Y- CURRY NOISE

An area where certain clouds might form:

> Z- CIRRUS ZONE

Comment: Yep yep yep! Keep the hits coming, man. B is 'robes', not 'robe', which should help.

Comment: Could this be formatted the way GordonK did his answer, so that readers don't have to scroll up and down to read each clue and its solution?

Comment: You got 'em all, guys! Well done. :)

Comment: @BaileyM: Pretty fun, as usual!

Answer (score 3):

*Partial answer, just to get the ball rolling and see if I am even on the right lines*

These seem to be related to:

> Keys on a keyboard

- A bearlike whale
- Attire of an ancient, mysterious sorcerer
- "Cool pointer!"

> DOWN ARROW (or could be up arrow)

- A blighted sort of metal

> ALT-EM?

- One who expeditions through deep time
- Keeps using the same data
- Providing someone with assets, maybe
- Destroyer of subatomic particles
- Wrath of the mailman
- Once again, the mongrels choose to partake
- Doctors act like pigs
- The Lord of the Sound

> VOLUME control

- Weeps over grains
- One who takes good care of his money?
- The companions we have
- Deface a rotting body
- An indecent vegetable

> CARET (a perversion of the word CARROT)

- One who wets the bed
- Scampers all over

> DASHes

- An unpleasant idiot
- Intriguing symbols on an intriguing object

> QUESTION MARKS

- The more voluptuous brother

> GREATER THAN

- Pots of snails
- An old decision point

> no RETURN

- Sounds like a spicy dish
- An area where certain clouds might form

> SPACE (molecular clouds, also known as stellar nurseries form in space)

Comment: This is clever, and fits a lot of my clues, but is not the direction I intended for this to go. +1 for sure, and remember while you're looking for answers -- I'm a fumbly, jumbly man when it comes to making puzzles! (Also, the title is a clue.)